# Erro na interface da listagem

Tags: javascript, html, lista, get

Estou fazendo um exercicio da faculdade, e quando vou aciono o click do botão resposavel por fazer a listagem, a minha tabela é refeita inteira, assim perco os nomes que deveriam ser fico na primeira linha, que são:

`-Codigo 
-Limite do Prazo 
-Nome do Usuario 
-Categoria 
-Comentarios`

Porem, a primeira linha já é logo substituida pelas informações do banco

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>Listagem</h3>
      <section>
        <button id="btListar" class="btn btn-info">Listar Atendimentos</button>
         <br />
         <br />
         <table class="table" id="tabelaLista" border="3">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
               <tr>
                  <td>Codigo</td>
                  <td>Limite do Prazo</td>
                  <td>Nome do Usuario</td>
                  <td>Categoria</td>
                  <td>Comentarios</td>
               </tr>
           </thead>
          </table>
  </section>
</div>
```

```
 var auxHTML = '';
 listaObjetos = JSON.parse(resposta);
 var total = listaObjetos.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    auxHTML += '<tr>' + 
            '<td>' + listaObjetos[i].code + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + listaObjetos[i].deadline + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + listaObjetos[i].userName + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + listaObjetos[i].category + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + listaObjetos[i].comments + '</td>' +
            '</tr>';
              }
  $('#tabelaLista').html(auxHTML);
```

Comment: @user140828 Funcionou perfeitamente! Gostaria de adicionar a correção para eu poder marca-la?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `.html(meuHTML)` do jQuery sobrescreve todo o HTML do objeto encontrado, para concatenar mais HTML com o já existente, você pode utilizar `.append(meuHTML)` para adicionar esse HTML no final do já existente, ou `.prepend(meuHTML)` para adicionar o HTML no início do já existente.

Comment: Obrigado! Com a explicação ficou perfeito!